# Why can't I further condense my query with WHERE clause in INSERT statement?

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery

Ignore the question marks (for Java prepared statements), but this query is for tracking who is viewing a specific reimbursement and stores their name in the "whose_hands" field when they are the current one viewing. If their username is in the viewed table, as well as the reimb_id that they have viewed, they aren't able to populate the whose_hands field again. The purpose of this is to pass the reimbursement form up a chain of users without repeating a viewer. It isn't letting me use the final WHERE clause, which is needed so I can insert the username in a specific reimbursement record. Is there a workaround for this?

```
INSERT INTO reimbursements(whose_hands)
VALUES(
  select username
  from users u
       join department d on u.department_id=d.department_id 
  WHERE position = 'DeptHead' 
  AND NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT username,reimb_id 
    FROM viewed v 
    WHERE v.username = u.username 
    and reimb_id=?) 
  where reimb_id = ?));
```

Comment: So you want to insert the new record in reimbursment table or update one of the column value of the table?

Comment: Sample data and desired results would clarify what you are trying to do.

Comment: *"Why can't I further condense my query with WHERE clause in INSERT statement?"* Because a SELECT statement can only have only **one** WHERE clause and you have **two** of them. Try using AND instead. Although you will also find that INSERT ... VALUES ( SELECT....)  is wrong and it should just be INSERT ... SELECT

Answer (score 1):

You Syntax is not correct. It should be -

```
INSERT INTO reimbursements(whose_hands)
select username
from users u
join department d on u.department_id=d.department_id 
WHERE position = 'DeptHead'
AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT username
               FROM viewed v
               WHERE v.username = u.username 
               and reimb_id=?);
```

Comment: That still doesn't solve the issue where I need to get the reimb_id to know what record I want to store the username in.

Comment: I didn't correctly understand your question. I just tried to fix the query. Please post some sample data and expected result.

Comment: I want to store the users who have viewed and approved a form in a new table (viewed) and only set the "whose_hands" field to a user in the same department who hasn't viewed it yet. I'm doing this by storing their username and the reimb_id they've approvedin the viewed table and checking to make sure that nobody views a specific reimbursement more than once. Only issue I'm having is that I can't add an additional WHERE clause outside of the Insert statement to let the query know which record I want to insert the user based on the reimb_id.

Comment: @kobs24 all of this extra detail helps, but it would be better in the question itself and not in comments on answers. (And I don't know what you mean by condensing a query.)

Answer (score 0):

You can't have two `WHERE` clauses in a SELECT statement. In this case I suggest that you replace the extra `WHERE` with an `AND`:

```
INSERT INTO reimbursements(whose_hands)
VALUES (select username
          from users u
          join department d
            on u.department_id = d.department_id 
          WHERE position = 'DeptHead' AND
                reimb_id = ? AND
                NOT EXISTS(SELECT username,reimb_id 
                             FROM viewed v 
                             WHERE v.username = u.username and
                                   v.reimb_id = u.reimb_id))
```

In the inner-most subquery you should replace `reimb_id=?` with `v.reimb_id=u.reimb_id` or `v.reimb_id = d.reimb_id`, but I don't know which of your tables has the `reimb_id` field in it. I show `u.reimb_id` in the example above, but if that's not right use whichever table alias is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I came up with. I realized that I needed to update the "whose_hands" field, not insert a new value:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE approve(department2 varchar2, reimb_id2 number)
IS
BEGIN
INSERT INTO viewed
VALUES(review_val.nextval,(SELECT whose_hands FROM reimbursements WHERE reimb_id = reimb_id2),
(SELECT reimb_id FROM reimbursements WHERE reimb_id = reimb_id2)); /* Stores current whose_hands and reimb_id in viewed table so they can't view again */
UPDATE  reimbursements
set whose_hands=
(select username
from users u
join department d on u.department_id=d.department_id 
WHERE position = 'DeptHead' AND department= department2
AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT username
               FROM viewed v
               WHERE v.username = u.username 
               and reimb_id=reimb_id2)) WHERE reimb_id = reimb_id2;
end;
```

I appreciate all of the help.